# newcommand, pgfplotsinvokeforeach, expl3: How to handle with several arguments of the kind '#...'

Tags: pgfplotstable, expl3, foreach, fp

I have `#1` for my newcommand. 
I have `##1` for my pgfplotsinvokeforeach-loop.

Now I would need something like `###1` for my comparing-method "`\fpcompareTF{##1<0}{333}{##1}`".

What is the right way here?

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, landscape=false]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsfonts}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

% fp-compare 
\usepackage{xfp}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\fpcompareTF}{mmm}
 {
  \fp_compare:nTF { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\section{Works}
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,...,3}{ % ----
\noindent\pgfplotstabletypeset[col sep=comma, row sep=\\,]{ 
#1, #1, 333 \\
} \\[1em]
}% ----

\section{Works not}

\newcommand\Test[1]{
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,...,#1}{ % ----
\noindent\pgfplotstabletypeset[col sep=comma, row sep=\\,
every column/.code={
\pgfkeysalso{postproc cell content/.style={
@cell content={
\fpcompareTF{##1<0}{333}{##1}%
}
}}},
]{ 
##1, ##1, -1 \\
} \\[1em]
}% ----
}
\Test{5}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Each new level of definition-inside-a-definition you don't _add_ a `#`, you _duplicate_ the `#`, so you need `#1`, then `##1`, then `####1`, then `########1`, then...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose the following:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\usepackage{xfp}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand {\fpcompareTF} { m m m }
  {
    \fp_compare:nTF { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand*\Test[1]{%
   \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,...,#1}{%
      \noindent\pgfplotstabletypeset[col sep=comma, row sep=\\,
        every column/.style={
          postproc cell content/.style={
            % /utils/exec={\message{Debug: #1, ##1, ########1^^J}},
            @cell content={\fpcompareTF{########1<0}{333}{########1}}
          }},
        ]{
        ##1, ##1, -1\\
      }%
      % Don't write the \\[1em] after the last line, otherwise this triggers an
      % underfull \hbox.
      \ifnum ##1<#1\relax \\[1em]\fi
   }%
}

\begin{document}

\Test{5}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

- Inside the replacement text of `\Test`, `#1` is replaced with the argument of `\Test`.
- One level down, inside the second mandatory argument of `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach`, `##1` is replaced with the tokens corresponding to what `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach` is iterating over.
- Next level is inside the first style definition: `####1` would represent the first argument of the `/pgfplots/table/every column` style, however this style takes no argument.
- Finally, inside the definition of the innermost style `/pgfplots/table/postproc cell content`, the first argument of the style is available as `########1` (eight `#` character tokens, because 8 = 2<sup>3</sup>).

If you uncomment my debug line:

```latex
/utils/exec={\message{Debug: #1, ##1, ########1^^J}},
```

you'll see the following in the LaTeX terminal output:

```
Debug: 5, 1, 1
Debug: 5, 1, 1
Debug: 5, 1, -1
Debug: 5, 2, 2
Debug: 5, 2, 2
Debug: 5, 2, -1
Debug: 5, 3, 3
Debug: 5, 3, 3
Debug: 5, 3, -1
Debug: 5, 4, 4
Debug: 5, 4, 4
Debug: 5, 4, -1
Debug: 5, 5, 5
Debug: 5, 5, 5
Debug: 5, 5, -1
```

As a small refinement, I replaced your `\\[1em]` with

```latex
\ifnum ##1<#1\relax \\[1em]\fi
```

otherwise, the last `\\[1em]` being alone at the end of a paragraph, causes an underfull `\hbox` (note: you could use the `ex` unit, since this is a vertical space that you are adding).

Comment: Very good explaination. ;)  Thx!